# pyodbc not enough values\n (0)

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pyodbc

```py
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE PEDIDO(
        CPEDIDO INT GENERATED AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        CCLIENTE INT NOT NULL,
        FECHA DATE NOT NULL
        )''')
    valores=[]
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        x=datetime.date(year=2022,month=11,day=i+1)
        valores.append((i,x)) 

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO PEDIDO VALUES(?,?);", valores) #doesn't work writing [valores] instead of valores
```

That results in:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Devart][ODBC][Oracle]ORA-00947: not enough values\n (0) (SQLExecDirectW)') #when inserting the instances

I have tried to save data in two different tuples: `cclients = (...) and dates=(...)` and then write:

```py
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO PEDIDO VALUES(?,?);", [cclients, dates]).
```

But doesn't work

Comment: The table has three columns. The tuples in `valores` have only two elements.

Comment: Why is this flagged with [tag:sql-server] when the backend is an Oracle database?

Comment: But, CPEDIDO is created as identity It should be auto-filled and autoincrement

Comment: Considering the Oracle error, I've gone ahead and changed the tag; please do ensure you tag correctly, @Rodkaiser . Different RDBMS can behave very differently, and their dialects can be *very* different too. Tagging the wrong RDBMS will often delay you getting helpful replies, and could even result in your getting answers that are not appropriate for your environment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advising. I will be more careful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Error: "ORA-00947: not enough values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69563882/sql-error-ora-00947-not-enough-values)

Answer (score 0):

Name the columns you are inserting into (and you may not need/require including the statement terminator `;` in the query):

```sql
INSERT INTO PEDIDO (CCLIENTE, FECHA) VALUES (?,?)
```

If you do not then Oracle will expect you to provide a value for every column in the table (including `CPEDIDO`).

Comment: Yes, its works. Thank you. And no, semicolon isn't neccesary, the costum of programming in c++ hahah

Answer (score 0):

You created a table with three columns, but you only provide two values in your SQL: `INSERT INTO PEDIDO VALUES(?,?)`. The column `CPEDIDO` is defined as `GENERATED AS IDENTITY`. This means that you can provide a value for this column, but you don't have to. But if you leave out this column your SQL statement has to be adjusted.

`INSERT INTO PEDIDO (CCLIENTE, FECHA) VALUES(?,?)`